# Rails: How to pass parameter to custom before_action class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

I am trying to use separate `AuthenticationFilter` class which takes user role as a parameter, but I canno't find any examples on how to do that. I tried using search and all I see is calling of methods like this:

```
before_action -> { some_method :some_value }
```

Or a custom class (like I have) but without parameter:

```
before_action AuthenticationFilter
```

These work, but how would I call `AuthenticationFilter` and give it a parameter such as `:superuser` ?

Do note: I wan't to use separate class, is this even possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okey, I managed to solve it.

I noticed that rails documentation mentioned `*_action` to call a method with the same name as * specifies. So, `before_action` seeks for a method named `before` in a given class.

Therefore I decided to make a block and call `AuthenticationFilter` before action directly by giving it the parameter:

```
before_action { |c| AuthenticationFilter.before(c, :superuser) }
```

Then I modified my `AuthenticationFilter` class to be like:

```
class AuthenticationFilter
  class << self
    def before(controller, role)
      puts "Called AuthenticationFilter with role: #{role}"
    end
  end
end
```

Hence, also noticed that using typical `only` and `except` rules works as well when doing:

```
before_action only: [:show, :edit] do |c| 
  AuthenticationFilter.before(c, :superuser) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your class initialization in a method?

```
before_action :set_authentication_filter

def set_authentication_filter
  # initialize your class here with custom parameters
end
```